# React- is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Buenas tengo el siguiento problema.
Gracias a un crack aca de la comunidad pude resolver el tema de mostrar o no un componente, es decir de mostrar o no el footer, el nav, etc, segun el componente que este cargado.

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import {Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './PerfilAdmin.css'

    // import './PerfilAdmin.css'
    const PerfilAdmin = ({handle}) => {
    console.log(handle)
    useEffect(()=>{
      const footer = async ()=>{
          try {
            handle(false)
            
          } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
          }
      }
      footer();
      return ()=> handle(true);
    
    },[handle])
```

Este es mi componente **DONDE NO SE RENDEREIZA(GRACIAS A ESA FUNCION) EL FOOTER**

```
×
TypeError: handle is not a function
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/guido/Desktop/Proyectos/reactproyectos/comercio/src/components/Login/PerfilAdmin.js:18
  15 |       }
  16 |   }
  17 |   footer();
> 18 |   return ()=> handle(true);
  19 | 
  20 | },[handle])
  21 |     //Construir un sistema de Logout automatico cuando se caduque el token o reiniciar el token
```

**El error que me tira.**

```
function App() {
const [footerFlag, setFooterFlag] = useState(true);
<>
<>
<>
  <Route path="/perfil/perfiladmin"  render={(props)=>{
      return <PerfilAdmin  {...props} handle={setFooterFlag} />
    }}  />
```

**Este este es mi Route y en App.js**

Luego al actualizar la pagina, el footer no se carga, y anda todo perfecto, estoy casi seguro que el problema esta, en como se utiliza el **useEffect()**, pero no encuentro el error hace bastantes dias.
Gracias por su tiempo !!

Comment: No veo cómo reproducir el error ¿Si pudieras describir con detalle en qué situación dispara el error? Saludos

Comment: Hola!! gracias por tu respuesta, el error ocurre cuando ese componente se monta, luego de que se monta por primera vez, si actualizo la pagina el error desaparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque cuando handle no es función, tu `try / catch` lo gestiona, pero no tu `return`, por eso te devuelve `TypeError: handle is not a function`.

Coméntame qué ocurre parchando esa sección y no dudes en subir tu código actualizado.

Comment: `useEffect(()=>{

  const footer = async ()=>{

      try {
        handle(false)
        
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
        return ()=> handle(true);
  }
  footer();

},[handle])`

Era tan facil como hacer eso, gracias por tu ayuda. Eso era lo que necesitaba que el return este dentro del **Try/catch**. Gracias estaba muy trabado!!

Comment: Genial! Para esto sirve la comunidad ;)